# How to correctly handle exceptions in a header?

Tags: c++, exception

I was making the exception handling of a program with multiple projects. I have decided to have a header "ExceptionHandling" in a project devoted to ExceptionHandling. Hence, I have come up with the following code:
    /* This object manages all possible exceptions: standards/automatic and specific */

```
#ifndef EXCEPTIONHANDLING_H
#define EXCEPTIONHANDLING_H

//#include "Stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <exception> // Standard exceptions
using namespace std;

// Longitude Exception
class LonEx: public exception
{
 virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
      return "**** ERROR: Longitude cannot be higher than 180 degrees\n\n";
  }
} exceptionLongitude;

// Negative Exception
class NegativeEx: public exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "**** ERROR: Negative value is not possible in ";
  }
} exceptionNegative;

// Xml exception (file cannot be opened)
class XmlEx: public exception
{
      virtual const char* what() const throw()
      {
        return "**** ERROR: XML parsed with errors. Unable to open file called ";
      }
} exceptionXml;

#endif
```

Then, in the file to catch the exception I will proceed like: "throw exceptionLatitude;".

The thing is that this give me the error LNK2005 (already defined) when I use it in two cpp files. I have tried to put the definition in a cpp file, but I haven't succeeded. Can anyone help me? I also want to know if it is good to have so many classes in a header. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't just declares types, you also declare objects... (and it should not compile, `what` should be public)

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std` in a header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to use global variables for your exceptions. Try to simplify and use local objects: instead of declaring classes and variables just declare classes, e.g.

```
class LonEx: public exception
{
 virtual const char* what() const throw()
 {
  return "**** ERROR: Longitude cannot be higher than 180 degrees\n\n";
 }
};
```

without `exceptionLongitude`. Then when you want to throw use

```
throw LonEx();
```

Comment: I have tried this, but this produces also the error LNK2005: "class LatEx exceptionLatitude" (?exceptionLatitude@@3VLatEx@@A) already defined in Rocket.lib(Rocket.obj) Rocket.lib(LLA.obj)

Comment: Where Rocket.h includes LLA.h, which includes the ExceptionHandling.h

Comment: Looks like somehow still your unnecessary exceptionLatitude object is present in the compilation results. Do the clean build - remove all .o files or do the equivalent in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

It's the exceptionLongitude, exceptionNegative, exceptionXml that are screwing you up.  And you don't need them.

Don't do

```
throw exceptionXml;
```

Instead do something like this:

```
throw XmlEx();
```

Just remove those definitions (exceptionLongitude, exceptionNegative, exceptionXml) from your .h, and you don't need a .cpp.

In short, declarations belong in a .h, definitions belong in a .cpp.  But you don't need to define *instances* of your exception classes, in order to use the *declarations* of the class *types.*

Answer (score -1):

If all you do is change the `what` message in those cases I'd use built in exceptions which have the appropriate constructors.

> ERROR: Longitude cannot be higher than 180 degrees\n\n
>
> ERROR: Negative value is not possible in

Are obviously an [`invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument)

> ERROR: XML parsed with errors. Unable to open file called

and is probably a [`system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) (file not found, permission denied).

For example

```
int mydiv(int x, int y){
    if (y == 0){
        throw std::invalid_argument("**** ERROR: Zero value is not possible as denominator.");
    }
    return x/y;
}
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/D5uU1t))